# Dynamic Broadcast receiver for Android widget

Tags: android, widget, broadcastreceiver, appwidgetprovider

The Android widget documentation (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#AppWidgetProvider) seems to indicate that you can set your own broadcast receiver to handle widget activity instead of using the AppWidgetProvider helper class. For reasons of activity/service structure this would be the most convenient way for me to manage the widget I would like to create.

Is it possible to do this with a broadcast receiver registered in OnCreate as opposed to on in it's own class. The trouble, I think, is that it then isn't registered in the manifest, and thus the widget never shows up in the list.

Documentation/examples of this setup are essentially non-existent. Does anyone know if this is possible or have a good example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this with a broadcast receiver registered in OnCreate as opposed to on in it's own class.

Not really. In theory, you could have *two* receivers registered, one in the manifest and one via `registerReceiver()`. I cannot imagine a scenario in which this would be a good idea, as your activity will not be running all of the time anyway, and so you need the manifest-registered receiver to do everything anyhow.

Comment: Ok. Well at least that clears that up. Thank you for your quick answer. If you will permit me a follow-up question, lets say I have a service that is bound to my main activity. What is the best way for me to then get information to/from the already running service from/to the widgetprovider? I've seen some suggestions that a broadcast receiver might be a good solution.

Comment: @Chris2222000: "What is the best way for me to then get information to/from the already running service from/to the widgetprovider?" -- ideally, you don't. Your service updates the app widget itself, using `AppWidgetManager`.

Comment: Thank you again for the nudge in the right direction. I was able to use AppWidgetManager from within the service like you said.